# Error: list indices must be integers but not string

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading a text file with a string of numbers and writing them into a JSON file. I have to write dependent on the index value of the text file. The following code has more error which I am unable to figure out.

```py
import json
filepath = '0000002_00448_d_0000015.txt'
line = []
data = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   print(line)
   line = line.split(',')
   print(line[0])
   print(line[1])
   print(line[2])
   print(line[3])
   print(line[4])
   print(line[5])
   print(line[6])
   print(line[7])
data['imagename']= []
data['imagename'].append({
   'bbox_left': line[0],
   'bbox_top': line[1],
   'bbox_width': line[2],
   'bbox_height': line[3],
   'score': line[4],
   'object_category': line[5],
   'truncation': line[6],
   'occlusion': line[7]

})


with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `data` as a list by doing:

```
data = []
```

Then, you try to use a string to index that list by doing this:

```
data['imagename'] = []
```

> This will not work because, as the error suggests, list indices can only be integers

---

I'm guessing that a possible answer for you would be to declare `data` as a dictionary instead.

That way, you can use the key and value system (here with key `"imagename"`) and append to the list inside the dictionary. All you need to change is:

```
data = {}
```

Comment: Oh yes, Such a lame mistake. Thank you

Comment: You can also define the key when declaring the variable: `data = { "imagename": [] }` .